# Megamenu with Triangle at Top

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, megamenu

I am using **bootstrap v4.4.1** navbar with a mega menu dropdown.

I wanted to add a triangle at the top of the dropdown menu.  I have figured out how to add the triangle, but I am unable to center the triangle within the parent `nav-link` instead of centering with the mega menu and/or dropdown menu.  Any thoughts on how to center the triangle in relation to the parent element?

```css
    .dropdown-menu::before {
        border-bottom: 10px solid #002a54;
        border-left: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-right: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -12px;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you would have to style a little bit differently if you want to center the traignle with the parent `.nav-link`. The idea is to set `.nav-link` position relative, and style its `:before` as the triangle and set its position to absolute.

#### Megamenu Layout

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown mega">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" />
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="mega-content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Triangle Style

Instead of `:before` on `.dropdown-menu`, use it on `.dropdown-toggle`. Also I only styled that when the dropdown is opened.

```css
.dropdown.mega.show .dropdown-toggle {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown.mega.show .dropdown-toggle:before {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #002a54;
    border-left: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -.5rem;        // .5rem is just the padding of the toggler
}
```

I used `:before` instead of `:after` on `.dropdown-toggle` because there is already another triangle/caret that is styled on `:after`. If you want, you can override the original one with yours, or, even better, only show yours when the dropdown menu is opened.

The tricky part to center it is to calculate the `left` offset.

Since you used `10px` border width to construct the triangle, and you want the center point of the triangle to be 50% of the width, then the left offset would be just `50% - 10px`:

[image]

#### Screenshot

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/to7uns64/36/